# Export all rows from DataTables in excel but exported only visible rows, but i am try to export all rows that visible or hidden in the pagination

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable, export, export-to-excel

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#downloadBtn').click(function() {
        var table = $('.table2excel').DataTable();
    var allRows = table.rows().data().toArray();
        var allRowsTable = $('<table>').append($('.table2excel').find('thead').clone()).append($('<tbody>'));
        for (var i = 0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
            allRowsTable.append($('<tr>').append(allRows[i]));
    }
    allRowsTable.table2excel({
            filename: 'data.xls',
            sheetName: 'Sheet1',
            exclude: '.noExl',
            preserveColors: true
    });
    });
});
```

this code for Export all rows from DataTables in excel but exported only visible rows, but i trying to export all rows that visible or hidden in the pagination.

Note: Using table2excel.js

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line of code:

```
var allRows = table.rows().data().toArray();
```

to this:

```
var allRows = table.rows( { page: 'current' } ).data().toArray();
```

This uses a [selector modifier](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) to select only the data in the currently displayed page.

The [selector modifier](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) documentation shows various different selection settings you can choose from.  It can be used in conjunction with [row selectors](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector) for additional control over the subset of data you want to select.

---

**Alternative Approach**

In case this may be of interest:

You are already using DataTables - so why not use its built-in support for exporting data to Excel? You can export just the current page using the same `page: 'current'` approach as shown above.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Brftip',
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'excel', 
        exportOptions: {
          modifier: {
            page: 'current'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  } );

} );
```

See [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html) for basic configuration of the buttons extension.

---

For the approach using `table2excel`, you are probably going to want to get the `<tr>` nodes from the DataTable, not the data as an array:

```
var allRows = table.rows().nodes();
```

And then in the `for` loop, you don't need to append an explicit `<tr>`:

```
allRowsTable.append(allRows[i]);
```

But (a) I have not tested this as I do not have `table2excel` - and (b) it would be much easier (in my opinion) to use DataTables for the export to Excel - as already shown above. (But maybe that does not meet your needs.)

Comment: Dear andrewJames,
Thanks your's response
But i am trying to export all rows that visible or hidden in the pagination

Comment: "_export all rows that visible or hidden in the pagination_" - In other words... Do you mean you want to export _all rows_? `var allRows = table.rows();` already gets all rows. Why is that not what you want? Can you clarify?

Comment: And why not use DataTables built-in Excel export functionality?

Comment: Yes i want all rows export in excel.
var allRows = table.rows().data().toArray(); this code fine but after export excel file is empty.

Comment: Yes andrewJames,
DataTables built-in Excel export functionality - alternative option is best.
Basically table2excel.js is liteweight :-P

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
var table = $('.exportexcel').DataTable();
$("#exportBtn").click(function(){
    $('<table>').append($(table.table().header()).clone()).append($(".exportexcel").DataTable().$('tr').clone()).table2excel({
        exclude: ".noExl",
        sheetName: 'Less Attendance Report',
        filename: "Less-Attendance-Report-" + new Date().toISOString().replace(/[\-\:\.]/g, ""),
        fileext: ".xls",
        exclude_img: true,
        exclude_links: true,
        exclude_inputs: true,
        preserveColors: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you explain the solution?