# Issue While Exporting Data table to Excel

Tags: jquery, datatable, export-to-excel

While exporting `datatable` to excel using `table2excel` plugin, it's exporting the `header` row **twice**. Why is it so?

below is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Scripts/assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Scripts/DataTables/DataTables-1.13.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="gridview">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>First Name of Person 1</td>
                        <td>Last Name of Person 1</td>
                        <td>State 1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>First Name of Person 2</td>
                        <td>Last Name of Person 2</td>
                        <td>State 2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>First Name of Person 3</td>
                        <td>Last Name of Person 3</td>
                        <td>State 3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>First Name of Person 4</td>
                        <td>Last Name of Person 4</td>
                        <td>State 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>First Name of Person 5</td>
                        <td>Last Name of Person 5</td>
                        <td>State 5</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button id="btnExport" class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-end"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>&nbsp;Export</button>
        </div>

        <script src="Scripts/multiselect/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <link href="Scripts/datepicker/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="Scripts/datepicker/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/regex.js"></script>
        
        <%--<script>
                $.noConflict();
            </script>--%>
        <%--<script src="Scripts/DataTables/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>--%>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/DataTables/DataTables-1.13.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
                if ($j('#gridview').find("table").length > 0) {
                    $j('#gridview').find("table").DataTable({
                        scrollY: "400px",
                        scrollX: true,
                        scrollCollapse: true,
                        paging: true,
                        fixedColumns: {
                            left: 1
                        },
                        "columnDefs": [{
                            "targets": 'no-sort',
                            "orderable": false,
                        }]
                    });
                }
                $j('#btnExport').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $j('#gridview').table2excel({
                        filename: "ExportSummary_" + (new Date).toLocaleTimeString().toString() + ".xls"
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Answer**

To prevent the duplicated header you need to comment out (or remove) these two settings:

```
scrollY: "400px",
scrollX: true,
```

You may also need to comment out (or remove) the `fixedColumns` setting. Currently, based on the code in your question, the table does not use this setting because the library is missing.

---

**More Explanation**

Why do you need to avoid the above settings?

Because DataTables creates a separate HTML table for the header, to support its scrolling and fixed column functionalities:

[image]

It appears as if the table2excel library is not aware of this and just exports what it finds in the DOM.

---

**Suggestion for a Better Solution**

To avoid this problem, and to have much better control over the Excel export function, you can use DataTables's [built-in support](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/simple.html) for exporting data to Excel.

See also: [Export all rows from DataTables in excel but exported only visible rows, but i am try to export all rows that visible or hidden in the pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75864060/12567365)